# How to distinguish between posted forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco and every page is a master page which is a sub master of another master basically. Therefore there are multiple PAGE_LOAD calls done per page and I need a way to distingiush between the forms posted. (So I can run conditionally processing to handle the posted data for each form).

I.E I have page.ispostback or whatever, but that will always file I was thinking I could include a hidden field in each form and check for the existance of that to find out which form was posted, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider this to be like any other webforms application.

So, don't necessarily try and handle your postbacks in the Page_Load event.

Let's say you have a Search 'form' and a Subscribe to newsletter 'form'. The submit button from each will cause the postback of the same page. You can attach an event to these buttons to catch the form submittal and handle the functionality of the submittal at this point rather than on Page_Load.

I usually separate all my mini forms into separate usercontrols with a codebehind which has a `btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` where I fire all my logic off.

You will also want to ensure that each collection of fields uses a unique `ValidationGroup` attribute value, so that the submitting of one form doesn't fire the validation of another form.

The advantage of this is that you can then build up a library of usercontrols for different features which are then all independent of each other. I often find that I can just lift these and reuse them from one Umbraco project to the next.